# saving imagejpeg output the file

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there something I am missing here? If I change    `imagejpeg($thumb, $newImage);`
 to  `imagejpeg($thumb);` it echos a load of unreadable characters. The thumb image directory exists.

My ultimate aim is to copy an image at a lower quality.

```
$filename = $imageDirectory . '/1.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;
$newImage = $imageDirectory . '/thumbs/1.jpeg';    
echo "image: <br>";
echo $filename;
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;    
// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);    
// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);    
// Output
imagejpeg($thumb, $newImage);
```

**UPDATE:** I now realize that the second parameter must be an image location with the new name. So... I have redefined $newImage. The path is fine... if I upload an image named 1.jpg to that location manually it exists at that path.

Comment: Do you want to store multiple images? You'll have to check the name of the file and possibly alter it if it already exists.

Comment: no no no, I am being very unclear. I have tried it both when the image already exists and when it doesnt (I think if it does exist then it will overwrite it anyway) but anyway my point is that it is not a problem with the path. I only one to store one image with this function above. I have no idea why this function doesn't work: $thumb is clearly the image I want to copy and $newImage is clearly the path of what will be the new image.

Comment: Is `$imageDirectory` relative or absolute?

Comment: It is absolute.

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions for the folder? You can check with [`is_writable()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php).

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to add the correct `Content-Type` header for the response if you want to output the image to the browser:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($yourimage);
```

Please check the [first example in the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php#example-3580) for more information. If you want to decrease the quality before outputting to your browser check the third example.

Comment: Thank you. When I tried that I got an internal error. Any case though, I want to save the file rather than show it. I just gave that as an example to show how it is definitely processing the image.

Comment: @Atrag if you check the third example instead of putting `NULL` put your location where you want to store the file (the third parameter decreases the quality).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my code then? Because that doesnt work. $thumbimageDirectory is a subfolder of where it finds the original image.

Comment: @Atrag could you update your question with your full code?

Comment: Sorry but due to confidentiality I cant do that. Even if I change $thumbimageDirectory to $imageDirectory directory it doesnt work. This script is at the end of the php file (within php brackets of course). What code fragment would you like to see exactly?